# Tensoring and retaining projectiveness

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra, projective-module

Let $A$be a unital associative ring,

If $A$ is not a projective $A$-bimodule, however $A\otimes A$ is a projective $A$-bimodule, can we conclude that $A\otimes A \otimes A$ is also projective?

Comment: ahah my bad. ok fixed :)